# Searching items in cart using laravel crinsane cart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shopping-cart

Am trying to get an item from a cart using [Crinsane Larvel Shopping Cart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart).
The documentation talks about using a closure. I do not understand the example provided.

I am using Laravel 5.3, am trying to search items from the shopping cart using information from the Request object. This is my code :

View

```
@foreach($cart as $item)
<td>
    <div>
        <a href='{{url("cart?id=$item->id&add=1")}}'> + </a>
        <input type="text" name="qty" value="{{$item->qty}}" autocomplete="off" size="2">
        <a href='{{url("cart?id=$item->id&minus=1")}}'> - </a>
    </div>
</td>
@endforeach
```

Route

```
Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@getCart');
```

Controller

```
public function getCart(){

    //increment the quantity
    if (Request::get('id') && (Request::get('add')) == 1) {

        $inputItem = Request::get('id');
        //$rowId = Cart::search(['id' => Request::get('id')]);
        $cartItem = Cart::get($rowId);
        Cart::update($rowId, $cartItem->qty+1);
    }

    //decrease the quantity
    if (Request::get('id') && (Request::get('minus')) == 1) {

        $inputItem = Request::get('id');
        //$rowId = Cart::search(['id' => Request::get('id')]);
        $cartItem = Cart::get($rowId);
        Cart::update($rowId, $cartItem->qty-1);
    }

}
```

Cart Content Collection

```
`Collection {#318 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da" => CartItem {#319 ▼
      +rowId: "027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da"
      +id: "1"
      +qty: 1
      +name: "Banana"
      +price: 35.0
      +options: CartItemOptions {#320 ▼
        #items: []
      }
      -associatedModel: null
      -taxRate: 21
    }
    "370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df" => CartItem {#321 ▼
      +rowId: "370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df"
      +id: "2"
      +qty: 7
      +name: "Melon"
      +price: 64.0
      +options: CartItemOptions {#322 ▼
        #items: []
      }
      -associatedModel: null
      -taxRate: 21
    }
  ]
}`
```

How can I use `Cart::search()` to find the Cart item with id 1 (banana)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just like this:

```
Cart::search(function($cartItem, $rowId) {
    return $cartItem->id == 1;
});
```

The `search` method is a wrapper for Laravel's [filter method on collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter).

A Closure is simply a function passed to a function that may or may not receive variables as arguments from the parent function.

If you want to use the `$request` variable inside of this Closure you will have to `use()` it:

```
Cart::search(function($cartItem, rowId) use($request) {
    return $cartItem->id == $request->id;
});
```

Of course make sure that `$request->has('id')` before you attempt to access that property.

Answer (score 1):

May this also helps someone.

Try to find by `where()` function like -

```
Cart::content()->where('id', $id);
```

Where `id` is the item id you want to search for.

Find it [here](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/issues/408#issuecomment-341414477).

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
$cart $item = Cart::content()->where('rowId', $id)->first();
```

if you have several cart instances:

```
$cart_item = Cart::instance('instance')->content()->where('rowId', $id)->first();
```

If you want to search based on the cart item options:

```
$cart_item = Cart::content()->where('options', function($q){
$q->where('name', 'simon');
})->first();
```